# splitting a single binary string value into array

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, binary

Is it not possible to do this? I've used the split() method before to split strings and store them into arrays. But I can't seem to do that for the binary string value..

E.g: I want "100000" to be split and stored in an array like so: someArray = {1,0,0,0,0,0}
But I can't seem to do that. It keeps resulting in something like this: someArray = {100000,0,0,0,0, ...}

This is what I have:

```
    result = Integer.toBinaryString(sum);

    String[] temp = result.split(" ");

    for(int num: resultArray) {
        for(String s: temp) {
            resultArray[num] = Integer.parseInt(temp[s]);
        }
    }

    for(int num: resultArray) {
        System.out.print(num + ",");
    }
```

Comment: You are splitting on a space, but there is no space in your binary string? You should split on `""` - i.e. "nothing". I think.

Comment: why wouldn't you use `% 10`?

Comment: @Prince: If you were to treat the string as a decimal number (which you'd have to in order for `% 10` to be useful), you could only deal with bit-strings up to 10 bits.  Anything more than that would cause overflow/wraparound, unless you went up to `long` -- and even then you still wouldn't be able to handle a full int's worth of bits.

Comment: You have two nested `for` loops… so for every value of `num` you loop over every element of `temp`. And without any error checking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to stay close to the spirit of your code (not necessarily the most efficient way of doing things):

You need to split on "nothing" - i.e.

```
String[] temp = result.split("");
```

Updated code based on updated question:

```
    String result;
Integer sum = 123;
int[] resultArray = new int[32];
Integer ii;
result = Integer.toBinaryString(sum);

    String[] temp = result.split("");
    ii = 0;
    for(String s: temp) {
      try {
        resultArray[ii++] = Integer.parseInt(s);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         // do nothing
      }
    }

    int n = ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
      System.out.print(resultArray[ii]);
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Output:

```
01111011
```

I limited the size of the array to 32 - typical for an int… If you expect that `sum` may be a longer type, you need to adjust accordingly.

Incidentally, it would be faster to use

```
string[] temp = result.toCharArray();
ii = 0;
for(char s: temp) {
        resultArray[ii++] = s - '0';
}
int n = ii;
for (ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
      System.out.print(resultArray[ii]);
}
```

since you know that `result` is purely numerical.

Comment: I did that before but it gave me an error.. I'll try it again

Comment: I think I know why I was getting the error. I updated the first post. Basically, if I want to create an int array copy of the String array, how would I correctly convert the string values over to int?

Comment: @B.V I have updated my answer… should work for you now. I prefer the last formulation - most compact. But earlier version shows how to modify your code to make it work; it is closer to your original.

Answer (score 0):

First convert `String` to `char` array then convert it to `int`

```
String str = "100000";
char ch []  = str.toCharArray();
int [] temp = new int [ch.length];
for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
     temp[i] = Integer.parseInt(""+ch[i]);
}
```